# How to set top position using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating custom div scroller and want to set top position of content div. My jquery code is as below:

```
containerOuterHeight=$("#messagePopUpContainer").outerHeight();
            contentOuterHeight=$("#content").outerHeight();
            contentTopPosition=$("#content").offset().top;
            alert("contentTopPosition"+contentTopPosition);
            alert(contentTopPosition-(containerOuterHeight/20));
            $("#content").offset().top=contentTopPosition-(containerOuterHeight/20);
            //$("#content").css("top",( contentTopPosition-(containerOuterHeight/20) ) + "px");
            alert("contentTopPosition"+$("#content").offset().top);
            //alert("Fontsize"+$('#content').css('font-size') );
```

and html is:

```
<div id='messagePopUpContainer' style='background-color:#ffffff; overflow: hidden;'>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='popupanchor' onkeydown='PopupKeyHandler("' + elmId + '");'></a>
```

```
<div id='content' style='width:350px'>' + methods.settings[elmId].text + '</div >
<div id='popupReturn'>Return</div></div></div>'
```

Comment: Try `$(element).position()` **(** `$(element).position().top` & `$(element).position().left` **)**

Answer (score 150):

You can use CSS to do the trick:

```
$("#yourElement").css({ top: '100px' });
```

Comment: Should not be

 ("propertyName", "propertyValue") 

?

Answer (score 68):

Accessing CSS property & manipulating is quite easy using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/). For example, to change single property:

```
$("selector").css('top', '50px');
```

Answer (score 15):

You could also do

```
   var x = $('#element').height();   // or any changing value

   $('selector').css({'top' : x + 'px'});
```

OR

You can use directly

```
$('#element').css( "height" )
```

The difference between `.css( "height" )` and `.height()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation. [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 10):

Just for reference, if you are using:

```
 $(el).offset().top
```

To get the position, it can be affected by the position of the parent element.  Thus you may want to be consistent and use the following to set it:

```
$(el).offset({top: pos});
```

As opposed to the CSS methods above.

Answer (score 3):

And with **Prototype**:

```
$('yourDivId').setStyle({top: '100px', left:'80px'});
```

Comment: `setStyle()` is only for dom elements. Use `css()` instead.